# Why Spring Boot application does not work with relative quality factor of HTTP?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, http-headers

Lets suppose I have a Spring Boot application:

```
dependencies {
  implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux:2.4.0")
}
```

with a simple RestController:

```
@RestController
class TestController {
  @PostMapping("/test")
  suspend fun test(@RequestBody request: Map<String, String>) {
    throw RuntimeException("test")
  }
}
```

When I use [httpie](https://httpie.io/) client to make requests, then the result looks like:

```
➜  ~ http post :8080/test param=value --verbose
POST /test HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json, */*;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 18
Content-Type: application/json
Host: localhost:8080
User-Agent: HTTPie/2.3.0

{
    "param": "value"
}


HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Content-Length: 309
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
Expires: 0
Pragma: no-cache
Referrer-Policy: no-referrer
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-XSS-Protection: 1 ; mode=block

<html><body><h1>Whitelabel Error Page</h1><p>This application has no configured error view, so you are seeing this as a fallback.</p><div id='created'>Wed Dec 09 22:24:52 MSK 2020</div><div>[906bb33e-5] There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).</div><div>test</div></body></html>
```

When I use cURL:

```
➜  ~ curl -XPOST localhost:8080/test -d '{"param": "value"}' -H "Content-type: application/json" -v
Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, POST is already inferred.
*   Trying ::1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 8080 (#0)
> POST /test HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.64.1
> Accept: */*
> Content-type: application/json
> Content-Length: 18
>
* upload completely sent off: 18 out of 18 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
< Content-Type: application/json
< Content-Length: 170
< Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
< Pragma: no-cache
< Expires: 0
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< X-Frame-Options: DENY
< X-XSS-Protection: 1 ; mode=block
< Referrer-Policy: no-referrer
<
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
{"timestamp":1607541989698,"path":"/test","status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error","message":"test","requestId":"7f249f68-9","exception":"java.lang.RuntimeException"}* Closing connection 0
```

The difference in header `Accept`. Httpie uses `Accept: application/json, */*;q=0.5` header with [**relative quality factor**](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html) 0.5 and, despite the fact that I requested JSON if possible (and it's possible), the application returns HTML representation.

Is it how Spring Boot should work and I do something wrong?

**UPD**: Everything works fine with Tomcat (`spring-boot-starter-web`). After some debugging I found that, when Tomcat used, errors are handled by `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController` and for Netty it is `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.reactive.error.DefaultErrorWebExceptionHandler`. It looks like the source of misbehavior is [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v2.4.0/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/reactive/error/DefaultErrorWebExceptionHandler.java#L257): when `MediaType.ALL`  is removed from `acceptedMediaTypes` .

Comment: Have you tried with `spring-boot-starter-web` instead of `spring-boot-starter-webflux`?

Comment: Thanks, with `spring-boot-starter-web` it works just fine. Updated my question.

Comment: If that works you probably caught a bug. Not sure if that is spring boot or core spring related, nonetheless I suggest creating an issue in one of those (looking at your debugging I would probably opt for Spring Boot).